# Regular expression for all strings with at least two 0s over alphabet {0,1}

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I was interested in finding regular expression for all strings with at least two $0s$ over alphabet $\{0,1\}$.

I attempted and formulated
$$(0+1)^* 0 (0+1)^* 0 (0+1)^*$$

Is this correct? And if not can somebody post and explain the correct one?

Comment: The regular expression _is_ correct.

Comment: Looks good to me. Who says not?

Comment: May be your problem is something else, your answer for this problem is correct.

Comment: A simpler expression would be $1^*01^*0(0|1)^*$.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by $(0+1)$.

Comment: @kaveh $(0+1)$ is quite standard, I see no confusion here. It is used interchangeably with $(0|1)$ and $(0\cup1)$.

Comment: @RanG., I want the OP to state what he means.

Comment: @Kaveh I have no doubt in your means. Yet, the OP might not understand the ambiguity (especially if the OP is new to this). IMHO, the answer of svick is the one that should be clarified as it uses the plus sign in a non-orthodox way.

Comment: @RanG., it is OP's question and I think having the clarification in the question is more appropriate.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right.

Answer (score -2):

It's incorrect for example because it does not match the string $100$.

The two zeroes would have to match the two zeroes in your regexp that are ouside the parentheses. Because of that, $(0\!+\!1)^*$ would have to match $1$, but it doesn't. That's because $(0\!+\!1)^*$ implies there has to be at least one zero for every $1$.

I think the regular expression that you meant is:

$$(0|1)^* 0 (0|1)^* 0 (0|1)^*.$$

Comment: I think the OP thought that $+$ meant the same as $|$, in fact, I thought that too when I read the question, but checking wikipedia does tell me that I am wrong, since $a+$ just means $aa^*$.

Comment: Yeah, that's most likely. And other people here probably thought the same.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you stressed that in your answer more (i.e. that $a+b$ does not mean $a|b$ but means $aa^*b$).

Comment: What? $a+b$ _does_ mean alternation in most _theoretical_ treatments of regular expressions. E.g., http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dwpeNRgjK68C&lpg=PA3&dq=mathematical%20regular%20expression&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @Artem:  I am pretty sure $a+b$ is not standard notation for $a a^*b$?  Probably $a^+b$ might be.  Where on Wikipedia did you see $a+$ meaning $aa^*$?